# Set function generator frequency to observe sine wave form in android app

Tags: arduino, android-bluetooth

I built an app to observe real-time graph. I set the sampling rate to 256hz in my Arduino code. I gave the output of 100hz through a function generator, but I obtained a random waveform instead of the sine waveform.

this is my Arduino code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h> //import Software Serial library

SoftwareSerial myStream(0, 1); //pins for Rx and Tx respectively
int ECG;
void setup()
{
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    pinMode(A0, INPUT); //LDR

    myStream.begin(115200);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    ECG = analogRead(A0);
    Serial.println(ECG);

    if (myStream.available() > 0)
    {
        char re = myStream.read();

        switch (re)
        {
        case 'E':
            start();
            break;
        }
    }

    //about 256Hz sample rate
    delayMicroseconds(3900);
}

void start()
{
    while (1)
    {
        myStream.print('s');
        myStream.print(floatMap(analogRead(ECG), 0, 1023, 0, 255), 2);
        //about 256Hz sample rate
        delayMicroseconds(3900);

        if (Serial.available() > 0)
        {
            if (Serial.read() == 'Q')
                return;
        }
    }
}

float floatMap(float x, float inMin, float inMax, float outMin, float outMax)
{
    return (x - inMin) * (outMax - outMin) / (inMax - inMin) + outMin;
}
```

This is my circuit diagram. In addition, I connected the oscilloscope output to A0 and common ground.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbwFn.png)

How can I get the sine waveform in my app.Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With your ~ 256 Hz sampling rate you just get about 2 *asynchronous* readings per period of a 100 Hz source.
analogRead adds (100 .. 150 µs on a 16 MHz Arduino) a considerable jitter to your delay.

Not sure about SoftwareSerial sending @115200. (receive won't work well at that speed)

And float is slow, too.

Not sure what you expect.

---

Check the raw data first:

```
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);  // allows for 10 char/ms
}

void loop() {
   static unsigned long oldmillis;
   if (millis() != oldmillis) {
    oldmillis = millis();
    // 1 kHz sample rate :  
    int ECG = analogRead(A0)*100L / 1024;
    Serial.println(ECG);  // 0 .. 99
   }
}
```

Perhaps add your start/stop communication or check with Arduino SerialPlotter.
When that's ok, test if you get those numbers via bluetooth to your app...

Comment: i am connecting the function generator output to the arduino. arduino sends the signal to bluetooth hc-06. bluetooth sends the signal to my mobile phone.  my app is plotting a graph but not a sine wave generated by signal genarator. even i reduced baudrate to9600 and delay to 0....my app doesn't plot a sine wave. i think when the bluetooth transmitting the values to lost some of the values. how can i correct it

Comment: If you have a 100 Hz sine wave, you probably want 2000 values / second transmitted to recognize the wave shape nicely. If every value is transmitted as text in a range 0 .. 1023 + newline, that's 4 characters per value. Requires true 115200 baud and no delays. Not sure if that works over SoftSerial.

Comment: even i tried with newsoftserial . but its not working.then how can i correct  it.